# Create a matrix blockwise attaching blocks like a stairway MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to build an Array containing of different blocks in the following way.
Given the block I want to repeat the block n-times so that it looks like this:

```
  A =  
  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0     
  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  
  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  

  and I want the Array look like this, n times repeating the scheme:

  newArray = 
  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0     
  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  
  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1                
                             1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
                             0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
                             0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  1 
 and so on...
```

With the free space being zeros, since the final array should be a sparse array either way.

How can I repeat and attach the block without using loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the leftward offset of each block with respect to a pure block-diagonal matrix is the number of rows of `A`, as in your example.

You can build a matrix `t` that 2D-convolved with `A` gives the result, as follows:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8]; % data matrix
n = 3; % number of repetitions
[r, c] = size(A);
d = c-r;
t = zeros(r*(n-1)+1, d*(n-1)+1);
t(1:(r*(n-1)+1)*d+r:end) = 1;
result = conv2(t,A);
```

This gives

```
A =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8

result =
     1     2     3     4     0     0     0     0
     5     6     7     8     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3     4     0     0
     0     0     5     6     7     8     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4
     0     0     0     0     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly but unfortunately not for my array size. _Requested 6309x288841 (13.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference_   Need to figure out how to use it.

Comment: `conv2` doesn't support sparse matrices, which seems to be what you need. `rahnema1`'s approach, second part, will probably be useful for you

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
n = 5; % number of repetitions
v = 3; % overlapping
s = size(A);

B = A(:,1:s(2)-v)
C = zeros(s(1),s(2)-v);
C(:,end-v+1:end) = A(:,end-v+1:end);

result = kron(eye(n) , B);
result(end,end+v)=0;
result(:,v+1:end) = result(:,v+1:end) + kron(eye(n) , C);
```

When the matrix size is large you can use sparse matrix:

```
n = 5;
v = 3; 
s = size(A);

B = sparse(A(:,1:s(2)-v));
C = sparse(s(1),s(2)-v);
C(:,end-v+1:end) = A(:,end-v+1:end);

result = kron(eye(n) , B);
result(end,end+v) = 0;
result(:,v+1:end) = result(:,v+1:end) + kron(eye(n) , C);
```

Comment: Works perfectly and fast! Thanks a lot!